# Beamer Presentation, embedding mp4 file

Tags: beamer, presentations, media9, embedding

Sorry for posting this, but I got 1 day left and literally the only thing I have to do is fix a video, so I can play it through PDF. I'm kinda panicking right now, so I will go straight to the problem:

The way I embed the video in my `beamer` presentation is through this:

```
\begin{frame}<article:0>[plain]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node[at=(current page.center)] {
           \movie[externalviewer]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth]{hut_176.png}}{hut.mp4}
           \movie[externalviewer]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth]{hut_176.png}}{hut.mp4}
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{frame}
```

It compiles perfectly, but when I try to open it through PDF, it pops up my Media Player, while I want it to play through the PDF. (Will only share my PDF in Zoom.)

I have tried a gazillion solutions I found online, most of them are not supported due to Flash Player, and others have similar or worse problems.

Any clue? I don't know if I'm in time to make it all over to Power Point.

Comment: Have you tried without option `externalviewer`?

Comment: Alrighty! This one seems to work but he resolution is GREATLY reduced (meaning its blurry) But ok

Comment: Is this code based (uses) on the `media9` package as the tag suggests? Because I do not find `externalviewer` in the `media9` manual (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/media9). *Update:* I see, this is part of the `multimedia` package that comes with `beamer`.

Comment: Yeah I have inserted both packaged. Thin I can't get it done. I'm trying now to transfer it to PPT.